# Large Image is not fit to image view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

[image]

I am creating chat app with firebase sending large image message that image is not fit to image view help me to solve this below codes

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_message_body"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: screenshots are uploaded

Comment: Please go through the image scale type properties. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: I think you have to use center crop instead of fitxy in scale type. i.e android:scaleType="centerCrop"

Comment: Don't load the entire image to a view as it may cause out of memory, scale down the image and load it, or use an image loading library like Glide to load the image, it knows how to load image better than you

Comment: Use glide library it will help to adjust the image

Comment: I am Using Picasso library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a specific size for height or width. I am using 200 and 100 dp it's up to you whatever you want

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_message_body"
         android:layout_width="200dp"  
         android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        />
```

Comment: Thanks for the response

Comment: if my answer is working please approved this as a answer

Comment: please read that i think you will understand https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers